# Get a file with SFTP using Pentaho

Tags: sftp, pentaho

I need to download files from sftp location using "**Get a file with SFTP**" in **Pentaho**. My connections goes through but i can't download any file from this location.

Can anyone please suggest, how can I download files using SFTP step in Pentaho?

Comment: Some more information is required: Are you getting an error? If so, which one? If not, then you're probably not specifying the folder and/or the file names correctly. It's often an issue of incorrect regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information is required: Are you getting an error? If so, which one? If not, then you're probably not specifying the folder and/or the file names correctly. It's often an issue of incorrect regular expressions. 
the following example works, assuming it's not a connection issue:

- **General** tab:

  - SFTP server name/ IP: `${your_sftp_host_here}`
  - Port: `22` (or else, if set differently on the source server)
  - Username: `${your_user_name}`
  - Password: `${your_password}`
- **Files** tab:

  - Remote directory: `${your_remote_directory}` (in relation to the root folder you land in)
  - Wildcard (regular expression): `${your_expression}` (for example: `.*2015-02-09.csv` would look for any csv file that starts with any prefix and ends with this particular date)
  - Target directory: `${your_local_target_dir}`

Should that not work for you, simply use the command line to check whether you can even connect to via SFTP, regardless of PDI.

Answer (score 0):

I too receive an error, my error is:
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
Algorithm negotiation fail

Might be because my personal laptop, where this instance of Kettle resides, cannot SFTP to the device due to firewall rules.